# Ruby: bundle not working with rbenv (path name contains null byte (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I have created a RubyGem and today, I was going to update the dependencies, but now after I go to the gem's directory and type `bundle install` I get [this](https://pastebin.com/QuHDj01z) error, whose last line is:

`` /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2663:in `directory?': path name contains null byte (ArgumentError) ``

I have reinstalled bundler, updated the system gem, etc., but nothing seems to be working. How can I avoid this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: are you sure you on the correct ruby version in the root path of your gem?  Can you show the output of `gem env`

Comment: I have `- RUBY VERSION: 2.6.2 (2019-03-13 patchlevel 47) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.6.0` could that be the problem? how could I change it?

Answer (score 10):

Check your `gemspec` file, in my case I replaced by mistake the double quotes with single quotes around the null character.

```
-    `git ls-files -z`.split('\x0').reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
+    `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of your project and run these commands

```
rbenv global 2.6.2
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
bundle install
```